# Tunning MYSQL have many schemas

Tags: mysql, schema, has-many

I have a DB MYSQL with many schema. Around 5k - 7k schemas.

My system sometime meet OOM Killer case.

Is that unnormal ?

we have 5 scheme different structure. The rest is the same and each schema corresponds to 1 user.

Is there any way to tunning up this db ?
[I haven't found a way yet]

How to reduce OOM error rate ?
[In my case, reduce inno buffer ~70% total RAM and resolve all slow query]

*NEW:
Because we have many schemas with **17 tables per schema, 1 table has ~10 partitions**. So in **datadir** each directory schema contains more than **25-30 files.**

Which is the way to reduce the number of files per schema?

Should I use tablespace to store all table not use partition to reduce?

Comment: If you have not already upgraded to MySQL 8.0, I recommend it. While they were developing it, I gave them feedback that they needed to support large numbers of tables and schemas. They said they tested 8.0 with a test case of 1 million tables to make sure it works.

Comment: It's not normal to have a schema per user - but may be appropriate in your case.

Comment: I've upgraded to version 8 already.
- I am wondering if there is a limit to the number of SCHEMAs?
- Each DB restart takes a long time to turn back on. Does reducing SCHEMA help the DB turn on faster or faster or slower due to the total amount of data stored?

Comment: In my case, each customer works separately on data. So the SCHEMA decomposition helps to reduce the frequency of accessing 1 table a lot and narrows the search scope.